# Are references to map entry's content valid after the entry (reference) is destroyed?

Tags: c++

Assuming I'm writing code like this:

```cpp
std::map<string, string> map_foo = {...};

void SomeJob(const string& key, const string& value) {...};

for (const auto& item : map_foo) {
    auto task = [&key = item.first, &value = item.second] {
        SomeJob(key, value);
    };
    // Run task in a thread pool
    executor->Schedule(std::move(task));
}

// Wait till all tasks finish.
```

The intent is to avoid any copy of `map_foo`'s content, as they will be valid till all tasks are done.

Will this code work as expected? My main confusion is **whether `&key = item.first` and `&value = item.second` are valid after `item` itself is destroyed after an iteration**. I feel they should because the reference points to the actual key and value of the map, which still exists, but I'm not certain.

Comment: In your capture, you assign `item.first` and `item.second`. Thereby, `item` is the reference to a map entry. I don't see any point where you erase something from the map. That a reference or pointer variable goes out of scope doesn't change anything on the referencee or pointee. (Shared pointers ignored...)

Comment: Another  concern is that you move the task but an invalid (moved from) entry will still be in the queue. It really should be "popped" from the queue not moved.

Comment: Will `map_foo` and all its elements used when creating the "tasks" still be alive when the "tasks" run? If even one of the elements of the map, or the map itself, no longer exists you have invalid references and can't use them.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The map and its items will remain valid, at least for the use of `SomeJob`

Comment: Unrelated: If you are using C++17 or later, use structured bindings in the `for` loop: `for(const auto&[key, value] : map_foo)`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for the suggestion! In that case, I assume `key` and `value` will be valid (in the same use case)?

Comment: @laike9m Yes, it's only a simplification.

Comment: @laike9m In C++20 and later, you can also capture the structured binding variables in the lambda, so `executor->Schedule([&]{ SomeJob(key, value); });` would be fine.

Comment: Note that the code doesn't match the question. No map entry is destroyed in the code sample. What got destroyed is a *reference* to a map entry, which is quite different.

Comment: @RaymondChen ack. let me update the question

Comment: Your feeling is justified. `key` still references a subobject of that map entry which didn't go anywhere.

Comment: thank you all. Anyone willing to post an answer, just to benefit future readers?